# I get an error trying to compile assembly code/C++ with G++

Tags: c++, assembly, winapi, x86, mingw32

So i wrote a small program just to test if everything is working.
It should take two inputs und output them summed up.

test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" int test(int a, int b);

int main(){
    int x = 0;
    std::cout << test(10, 20);
    std::cin >> x;
    return 0;
}
```

test.s:

```
.global test

test:

    mov %eax, %ecx
    add %eax, %edx

    ret
```

I then tried compiling it with g++:
*g++ -o main.exe test.cpp test.s*
But i get an error:  *undefined reference to `test'*

I am completely new to programming with assembly. Any advice?

Comment: Your compilation command only compiles "test.cpp", but you also need to compile and link "test.s" in order to have the reference to `test` be resolved

Comment: @UnholySheep Compiling g++ -o main.exe test.cpp test.s results in the same error

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I am using Windows 11

Comment: I assume with MinGW targeting 32 bit windows program? If so you will need to add an `_` (underscore) to the assembly code labels that are to bee visible to other objects. So you'd be use `_test:` . The `_` is part of the naming convention in Wi32 COFF objects and win32 executables.

Comment: @MichaelPetch With the underscore it works, thanks so much!

Comment: Does this actually result in the desired value? It seems like AT&T syntax with the percent sign identifiers but the register operand order seems like Intel syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include `test.s` file in your build command:

```
g++ -o main.exe test.cpp test.s
```

otherwise the compiler will complain that the `test` function is undefined because it cannot find it

Comment: Sorry, pasted the wrong command in my question. Your awnser is the command i used, it results in the same error

Comment: it looks like you have problems with your installed g++ version then. Add some details such as the operating system, and the result of running `g++ --version` and `g++ -v`

Comment: No problem with his g++ version. He's using a Win32 g++ tool chain so the additional issue is the necessary `_` on symbols with Win32 COFF object and Win32 PE executables.